How to stream a nested structure in JavaScript/TypeScript?
I am implementing a REST API endpoint that returns lists of objects of different types. The list will have roughly the following shape:
{
    "type1": [
        { "prop1": "value1a", ... },
        { "prop1": "value1b", ... },
        ...
    ],
    "type2": [
        { "prop2": "value2a", ... },
        ...
    ],
    "type3": [
        { "prop3": "value3a", ... },
        ...
    ]
}

As the list of objects can get quite long, I would like to emit it as a stream, so that neither the server nor the client have to keep the whole list in memory and the client can already start processing the data before all of it has arrived. The JSON object would be streamed in chunks like this:
{
    "type1": [

        { "prop1": "value1a", ... },

        { "prop1": "value2b", ... }

    ],
    "type2": [

        ...

So far, so good.
To make it easier for people to use my REST API, I want to provide a TypeScript library that provides methods to call the various API endpoints. My problem is that JavaScript streams are made for flat structures, but I’m trying to find a way to stream a nested structure.
How can I stream a nested structure in JavaScript/TypeScript?

I would say option 2, but I don't understand this -> structure is quite inconsistent ,  your only making it flat to 1 level, and if you use async iterators to consume it would be trivial to consume.

It's true that in this case the flattened stream is not that difficult to consume. But there might be other cases where the object structure is much more nested and streamed objects appear somewhere deep in the object hierarchy. I'm wondering if there is a general good way to represent such nested streamed structures.

I think it all depends on how your data is partitioned, it doesn't really matter how deep the structure is as long as your can partition the data into logical chunks.  You could maybe just create separate requests.  eg. one request might be to get type1, type2, type3 etc, then another request you get type1 -> prop1,prop2,prop3 etc,  you could go as deep as you want.  This way would be very efficient on memory usage, as you just JIT the data in on each request.  Similar I suppose to your stream of streams, but simpler to implement.

"I am implementing a REST API endpoint that returns lists of objects of different types" - really for proper REST you should have a single list per endpoint. Not multiple ones. Especially if you want to stream them. Use HTTP2+ and it'll be no problem to have multiple independent streams on the same connection even.

Those nested streams don't make sense. Why would you want to consume the outer stream in a particular order? You should identify the substreams by their type, not by their order in the parent stream. The proper representation for that is { type1: ReadableStream<Type1Object>, type2: ReadableStream<Type2Object>, type3: ReadableStream<Type3Object> }. You can trivially send that as a flat stream, then split in your library, before you hand the resulting streams to the consumers.

The REST API in my question is only an example. Of course there are valid use cases where a REST API returns multiple objects of different types, for example, a REST endpoint that creates an object containing multiple sub-objects and should return all of them at once. If the endpoint only returned the main object without its descendants, separate calls would be needed that can only be made when the result of the first call containing the object ID has arrived, which would drastically decrease performance.

You need to consume the outer stream in a particular order because it arrives in a particular order. If you consume it in a different order than how it arrives, the items need to be cached in memory until they are consumed, which defies the whole purpose of streaming them. In the example representation that you gave, the sub streams still need to be consumed in the right order, but the type does not give a very good indication that this is the case.

You can't have that. Either they are independent streams, and they will be consumed at whatever rate each consumer chooses, or you don't have independent streams but should use a single flat stream with a single consumer. Which one do you want?

"If the endpoint only returned the main object without its descendants, separate calls would be needed that can only be made when the result of the first call containing the object ID has arrived" - yes, that is how REST is supposed to work. Use GraphQL if you want everything the client needs in a single request. Of course, if the descendant objects are small/few enough, you may embed them in every REST response for the parent object, but given there are so many that you see a benefit in streaming them I did not consider that to be the case.

Things like expansions are common with REST APIs in the wild. But this question is not about how a REST API should be designed, it is about how to represent a nested structure as a stream. If the API were to use GraphQL and I would want to stream its response, the problem would be exactly the same.

What is the purpose of streaming this? Is the object too large to keep in memory before sending? If so, does it even make sense for the receipient to reassemble this? My feeling is that perhaps this is a bit of a red flag and may be better to rethink this a bit.

After experimenting with this for a while, here are two approaches that I have come up with along with their advantages and disadvantages.
Approach 1: flattened entries stream
Flatten the stream into a stream of entries (ReadableStream<["type1", Type1Object] | ["type2", Type2Object] | ["type3", Type3Object]>).
Flattened entries streams are rather easy to create, as the data already arrives in the form of a flat stream (of bytes) from the REST API, so it just needs to be transformed into a stream of entries.
The main problem that I have experienced while trying to consume flattened streams is that their type doesn’t guarantee or even indicate in what order the items arrive. Let’s assume a ReadableStream<["type1", Type1Object] | ["type2", Type2Object] | ["type3", Type3Object]> and I want to first process the "type1" objects and then the "type2" objects. While the REST API itself might guarantee that first all the "type1" objects will arrive, then all the "type2" objects and then the "type3" objects, and I might mention this in the documentation of my code, the ReadableStream type itself does not guarantee this order, so it would be bad style to rely on it (and the order of the REST API response might change). Instead, a consumer would have to iterate over the whole stream in order to be sure to have all the objects of one type. This means that consumers are either forced to implement their code in a way that manages to handle all object types in parallel, or they have to cache a lot of objects in memory before being able to process them.
Approach 2: nested streams
Return a nested stream for each object type (ReadableStream<(ReadableStream<Type1Object> & { type: "type1" }) | (ReadableStream<Type2Object> & { type: "type2" }) | (ReadableStream<Type3Object>]> & { type: "type3" })). The advantage of this approach is that it resembles the underlying object structure much more and can be iterated over in the same way as the plain object could be. Individual sub-streams can be teed or piped to different destinations if needed.
A common way to consume a nested stream would be through a nested iteration:
for await (const subStream of parentStream) {
    for await (const chunk of subStream) {
        // Do something with chunk
    }
}

Producing a stream that can be consumed in this way is not too complicated, as the chunks are consumed in the order they arrive from the REST API. However, there are many other ways how such a stream can be consumed, and this is where the main challenge with this approach emerges: It is very difficult to implement it right. A nested stream needs to handle the following cases for example:

A consumer might first iterate over the whole parent stream and then start consuming some of the sub streams later. If the nested stream is not implemented right, there is a chance that the parent stream will get stuck if the sub streams are not consumed immediately.
Related to that, a consumer might put some of the sub streams aside and consume them later in a different order than how they have arrived. The nested stream needs to buffer chunks in order to support such cases.
A consumer might cancel a sub stream if they don’t require the rest of its chunks, either by calling break in the iteration or by calling subStream.cancel(). The nested stream needs to handle this in a way that the parent stream continues emitting the rest of the sub streams and that the rest of the sub streams emit their data.
The source stream might abort. The nested stream needs to make sure that this abortion is forwarded to the parent stream and to all active sub streams, so that the consumer is notified about the abortion no matter which part of the nested stream they are currently consuming. If not implemented right (for example the abortion is forwarded only to the parent stream), there is a chance that the iteration will get stuck waiting for a chunk on a sub stream.
A consumer might want to tee the parent stream. This needs to tee all the sub streams as well.
With all the challenges above, the implementation should still be able to apply back pressure if neither the parent stream nor any of the sub streams are currently being consumed.

If an implementation manages to get all of these right, nested streams can be a useful (although unusual) way to represent this data. As an inspiration, you can have a look at my implementation of StreamSplitter, which converts a flattened stream to a nested stream (with the assumption that the chunks arrive in order).
Consumers of a nested stream need to keep in mind that individual sub streams need to be discarded by calling subStream.cancel() if not used, otherwise their data will remain in memory.
Conclusion
From the experience that I’ve gathered so far, I think that each of the approaches has advantages/disadvantages in certain scenarios. If implemented right, nested streams are more versatile, since they can be easily converted to flattened streams if needed, which is not possible the other way round. But they require a lot more thought and testing to implement. So my personal conclusion is that when time and resources allow, nested streams are the better option for the user, but otherwise, flattened streams also work and are much easier to implement.
